# How to get JSON data into option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting JSON in the following format (as array of objects)

```
[{"0":"Ahmednagar","city_name":"Ahmednagar","1":"1","city_id":"1"},{"0":"Akola","city_name":"Akola","1":"2","city_id":"2"},{"0":"Amravati","city_name":"Amravati","1":"3","city_id":"3"},{"0":"Aurangabad","city_name":"Aurangabad","1":"4","city_id":"4"},{"0":"Beed","city_name":"Beed","1":"5","city_id":"5"},{"0":"Bhandara","city_name":"Bhandara","1":"6","city_id":"6"},{"0":"Buldhana","city_name":"Buldhana","1":"7","city_id":"7"},{"0":"Chandrapur","city_name":"Chandrapur","1":"8","city_id":"8"},{"0":"Dhule","city_name":"Dhule","1":"9","city_id":"9"},{"0":"Gadchiroli","city_name":"Gadchiroli","1":"10","city_id":"10"},{"0":"Gondia","city_name":"Gondia","1":"11","city_id":"11"},{"0":"Hingoli","city_name":"Hingoli","1":"12","city_id":"12"},{"0":"Jalgaon","city_name":"Jalgaon","1":"13","city_id":"13"},{"0":"Jalna","city_name":"Jalna","1":"14","city_id":"14"},{"0":"Kolhapur","city_name":"Kolhapur","1":"15","city_id":"15"},{"0":"Latur","city_name":"Latur","1":"16","city_id":"16"},{"0":"Mumbai City","city_name":"Mumbai City","1":"17","city_id":"17"},{"0":"Mumbai Suburban","city_name":"Mumbai Suburban","1":"18","city_id":"18"},{"0":"Nagpur","city_name":"Nagpur","1":"19","city_id":"19"},{"0":"Nanded","city_name":"Nanded","1":"20","city_id":"20"},{"0":"Nandurbar","city_name":"Nandurbar","1":"21","city_id":"21"},{"0":"Nashik","city_name":"Nashik","1":"22","city_id":"22"},{"0":"Osmanabad","city_name":"Osmanabad","1":"23","city_id":"23"},{"0":"Palghar","city_name":"Palghar","1":"36","city_id":"36"},{"0":"Parbhani","city_name":"Parbhani","1":"24","city_id":"24"},{"0":"Pune & Pimpri-Chinchwad ","city_name":"Pune & Pimpri-Chinchwad ","1":"25","city_id":"25"},{"0":"Raigad","city_name":"Raigad","1":"26","city_id":"26"},{"0":"Ratnagiri","city_name":"Ratnagiri","1":"27","city_id":"27"},{"0":"Sangli","city_name":"Sangli","1":"28","city_id":"28"},{"0":"Satara","city_name":"Satara","1":"29","city_id":"29"},{"0":"Sindhudurg","city_name":"Sindhudurg","1":"30","city_id":"30"},{"0":"Solapur","city_name":"Solapur","1":"31","city_id":"31"},{"0":"Thane","city_name":"Thane","1":"32","city_id":"32"},{"0":"Wardha","city_name":"Wardha","1":"33","city_id":"33"},{"0":"Washim","city_name":"Washim","1":"34","city_id":"34"},{"0":"Yavatmal\t","city_name":"Yavatmal\t","1":"35","city_id":"35"}]
```

ajax call to get json

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#select_state").change(function() {
          var $state_var=$('#select_state').val();
          alert("Selected State Value "+$state_var);
          //make the ajax call
          $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/location.php',
            type:'GET',
            data: {
              state_name : $state_var
            },
            success: function(city_list) {              
                console.log(city_list);


                var options = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < city_list.length; i++) {
                        var city = city_list[i]; 

                        options += '<option value="' + city.city_id + '">' + city.city_name + '</option>';
                    }

                $('#select_city').html(options);
                $('#select_city').show();

            }
          });
      });
  });
```

Now it gives me only **undefined** is option list

Comment: After `type:'GET',` add `dataType;'json',` and then check

Comment: Thanks, i was forgotten to give **dataType:'json'**

Comment: yes it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:-

```
dataType;'json',
```

In your `$.ajax` code so that your response is automatically parsed and `success` function will execute properly.

Like below:-

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/location.php',
      type:'GET',
      dataType:'json', // add this
      data: {
          state_name : $state_var
      },.....rest code
```

Comment: What's the difference between `dataType json` and `no` in return value?

Comment: @artgb  when you are sending json response to ajax as a return, then you have to parse it to JavaScript object for further use, if you have `dataType:'json',` then it will done automatically. Otherwise you have to do it manually with `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: GodLike advice for me